# How to configure test framework as per platform in ARTOS?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, artos

We are using ARTOS framework to test product. Windows machine is used during development of the test cases but Linux remote server runs overnight testing using committed test cases. 
Every time I commit test cases I have to manually change configurations to disable “stop on fail” feature. Is there a way to support different configuration for development and production environment?

Following is my sample file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="framework_configuration.xsd">
  <organization_info profile="dev">
    <property name="Name">&lt;Organisation&gt; PTY LTD</property>
    <property name="Address">XX, Test Street, Test address</property>
    <property name="Country">USA</property>
    <property name="Contact_Number">+1 1234567</property>
    <property name="Email">artos.framework@gmail.com</property>
    <property name="Website">www.theartos.com</property>
  </organization_info>
  <logger>
    <!--LogLevel Options : info:debug:trace:fatal:warn:all-->
    <property name="logLevel">debug</property>
    <property name="logRootDir">.\reporting\</property>
    <property name="logSubDir">SN-123</property>
    <property name="enableLogDecoration">false</property>
    <property name="enableTextLog">true</property>
    <property name="enableHTMLLog">false</property>
    <property name="enableExtentReport">true</property>
  </logger>
  <smtp_settings>
    <property name="ServerAddress">smtp.gmail.com</property>
    <property name="SSLPort">587</property>
    <property name="SMTPAuth">true</property>
    <property name="SendersName">John Murray</property>
    <property name="SendersEmail">test@gmail.com</property>
    <property name="emailAuthSettingsFilePath">.\conf\user_auth_settings.xml</property>
    <property name="ReceiversEmail">test@gmail.com</property>
    <property name="ReceiversName">Mac Murray</property>
    <property name="EmailSubject">Artos Email Client</property>
    <property name="EmailMessage">This is a test Email from Artos</property>
  </smtp_settings>
  <features>
    <property name="enableGUITestSelector">true</property>
    <property name="enableGUITestSelectorSeqNumber">true</property>
    <property name="enableBanner">true</property>
    <property name="enableOrganisationInfo">true</property>
    <property name="enableEmailClient">false</property>
    <property name="enableArtosDebug">false</property>
    <property name="generateEclipseTemplate">false</property>
    <property name="generateTestScript">true</property>
    <property name="stopOnFail">true</property>
  </features>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use profiles in ARTOS which lets you choose configuration using command line.

For Example: You can call your one profile "DEV" and one "PROD". See code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="framework_configuration.xsd">

  <!-- DEV PROFILE BELOW -->
  <organization_info profile="DEV">
    <property name="Name">&lt;Organisation&gt; PTY LTD</property>
    <property name="Address">XX, Test Street, Test address</property>
    <property name="Country">USA</property>
    <property name="Contact_Number">+1 1234567</property>
    <property name="Email">artos.framework@gmail.com</property>
    <property name="Website">www.theartos.com</property>
  </organization_info>
  <logger profile="DEV">
    <!--LogLevel Options : info:debug:trace:fatal:warn:all-->
    <property name="logLevel">debug</property>
    <property name="logRootDir">.\reporting\</property>
    <property name="logSubDir">SN-123</property>
    <property name="enableLogDecoration">false</property>
    <property name="enableTextLog">true</property>
    <property name="enableHTMLLog">false</property>
    <property name="enableExtentReport">true</property>
  </logger>
  <smtp_settings profile="DEV">
    <property name="ServerAddress">smtp.gmail.com</property>
    <property name="SSLPort">587</property>
    <property name="SMTPAuth">true</property>
    <property name="SendersName">John Murray</property>
    <property name="SendersEmail">test@gmail.com</property>
    <property name="emailAuthSettingsFilePath">.\conf\user_auth_settings.xml</property>
    <property name="ReceiversEmail">test@gmail.com</property>
    <property name="ReceiversName">Mac Murray</property>
    <property name="EmailSubject">Artos Email Client</property>
    <property name="EmailMessage">This is a test Email from Artos</property>
  </smtp_settings>
  <features profile="DEV">
    <property name="enableGUITestSelector">true</property>
    <property name="enableGUITestSelectorSeqNumber">true</property>
    <property name="enableBanner">true</property>
    <property name="enableOrganisationInfo">true</property>
    <property name="enableEmailClient">false</property>
    <property name="enableArtosDebug">false</property>
    <property name="generateEclipseTemplate">false</property>
    <property name="generateTestScript">true</property>
    <property name="stopOnFail">true</property>
  </features>

  <!-- PROD PROFILE BELOW -->
  <organization_info profile="PROD">
    <property name="Name">&lt;Organisation&gt; PTY LTD</property>
    <property name="Address">XX, Test Street, Test address</property>
    <property name="Country">USA</property>
    <property name="Contact_Number">+1 1234567</property>
    <property name="Email">artos.framework@gmail.com</property>
    <property name="Website">www.theartos.com</property>
  </organization_info>
  <logger profile="PROD">
    <!--LogLevel Options : info:debug:trace:fatal:warn:all-->
    <property name="logLevel">debug</property>
    <property name="logRootDir">.\reporting\</property>
    <property name="logSubDir">SN-123</property>
    <property name="enableLogDecoration">false</property>
    <property name="enableTextLog">true</property>
    <property name="enableHTMLLog">false</property>
    <property name="enableExtentReport">true</property>
  </logger>
  <smtp_settings profile="PROD">
    <property name="ServerAddress">smtp.gmail.com</property>
    <property name="SSLPort">587</property>
    <property name="SMTPAuth">true</property>
    <property name="SendersName">John Murray</property>
    <property name="SendersEmail">test@gmail.com</property>
    <property name="emailAuthSettingsFilePath">.\conf\user_auth_settings.xml</property>
    <property name="ReceiversEmail">test@gmail.com</property>
    <property name="ReceiversName">Mac Murray</property>
    <property name="EmailSubject">Artos Email Client</property>
    <property name="EmailMessage">This is a test Email from Artos</property>
  </smtp_settings>
  <features  profile="DEV">
    <property name="enableGUITestSelector">true</property>
    <property name="enableGUITestSelectorSeqNumber">true</property>
    <property name="enableBanner">true</property>
    <property name="enableOrganisationInfo">true</property>
    <property name="enableEmailClient">false</property>
    <property name="enableArtosDebug">false</property>
    <property name="generateEclipseTemplate">false</property>
    <property name="generateTestScript">true</property>
    <property name="stopOnFail">false</property>
  </features>
</configuration>
```

To choose right profile, In your command line argument you can type something like this:

For Development profile

`java -cp ".\lib\*;.\bin\" [Main] --testscript="testscript.xml" --profile="DEV"`

For Production profile

`java -cp ".\lib\*;.\bin\" [Main] --testscript="testscript.xml" --profile="PROD"`

Answer (score 1):

Use profile feature.
You can use command line parameter `-p="YourProfileName"` which will choose correct profile for you.